# Php add calendar months to a date

Tags: javascript, php, date, calendar

I would like to add some calendar month to a date. I have done in javascript, but I would make the same function in Php (I'm newer).
This is javascript code:

```js
var date = '2017-08-30';
var addMonth=6;
var arrDate = date.split("-");
var dateSrt = new Date(date);
var newSrvDate = new Date(dateSrt.getTime());

newSrvDate.setMonth(dateSrt.getMonth() + (addMonth), arrDate[2]);
if (newSrvDate.getMonth() > (dateSrt.getMonth() + (addMonth)) % 12) { 
    newSrvDate.setDate(0); 
}
srvDay = new Date(newSrvDate.getFullYear(), newSrvDate.getMonth() , newSrvDate.getDate());
alert("Start:"+dateSrt);
alert("End:"+srvDay);
```

In this case if I add 6 months to 2017-08-30 will be 2018-02-30, but it doesn't exist, so it become 2018-03-02.
I would like that if the date exist ok, in other case the last day of the month...

I hope I'm clear... the code work perfectly in javascript, but I can not reproduce it in php

Any suggestions ere welcome

Comment: Have you looked into PHP's [DateTime class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php), with [DateTime->add()](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check date with `checkdate()` if valid date or not in  Gregorian dates. And then if not exist then subtract 1 day (24 hours) from the date and again check exist or not. Just like as in following code without using any class (plain PHP).

**Here you JS equivalent code in PHP.**

```
$date = '2017-08-30';
$newDate = strtotime($date)+6*30*24*60*60;
$exploded = explode('-',$date);
$month = $exploded[1];
$year = $exploded[0];
$day = $exploded[2];

$new_month = $exploded[1]+6;
if($new_month>12){
    $month = $new_month-12;
    $year = $year+1;
}
else{
    $month = $new_month;
}
echo $year."-".$month."-".$day;

//Function to check date recursively.............
function check_date($year,$month,$day){
    if(!checkdate($month,$day,$year)){
        $day = $day-1;
        return check_date($year,$month,$day);
    }
    else{
        return $year."-".$month."-".$day;
    }
}

$final_date = check_date($year,$month,$day);
echo date("Y-m-d",strtotime($final_date));
```

But I would recommend you to look at into DateTIme class and also look `date()`.

**Note:** This is the code where the day of the month will be preserved and **answer** for you question "**I would like that if the date exist ok, in other case the last day of the month....**"

Answer (score 0):

It's easy using `DateTime`and `DateInterval` PHP classes.

The following code will take a string formatted as "Y-m-d" (4 digits year, 2 digits month, 2 digits day, dash separated) convert it to a `DateTime` object, add 6 months, then turn back the `DateTime` into a string according to the original format.

The code is actually self explanatory...

```
<?php
$dateStr = '2017-08-30';

$date = DateTime::createFromFormat( 'Y-m-d', $dateStr );
$interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('6 months');
$date->add( $interval );

$dateStr = $date->format( 'Y-m-d' );

echo "$dateStr\n"; // outputs 2018-03-02
```

For your reference:

http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php

http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.createfromdatestring.php